# Is it possible to add just one page to existing sire project via PUG when the rest is written in simple HTML5?

Tags: html, node.js, pug

So I have a simple site at hand, written with *HTML5* and *Less CSS*. Now I have to add a market-page to it and I found a comprehensive guide on how to do that with *ExpressJS + PUG + MySQL*.

But before I do that I would like to know whether I'll have to convert the whole site project into new structure or I will be able to simply add a market page to already existing project without generally changing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use Pug and HTML independently, however It's fairly easy to convert/switch between the two. There are plenty of conversion tools online (https://html2jade.org/), and while I don't recommend this- you might even be able to mix and match HTML within your Pug code.